# Generate a 2D data structure from a dictionary, using keys as coordinates

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing a tuple as the key and an integer as the value.
Here is an example of the format:

```
{
(2015, aaaa) : 5
(2015, bbbb) : 2
(2014, aaaa) : 8
(2014, bbbb) : 1
}
```

I want to output this information in a 2D array (or similar data structure) like so:

```
----------------
|    |2014|2015|
----------------
|aaaa|   8|   5|
|bbbb|   1|   2|
----------------
```

The dictionary could possibly be thousands of lines long. What would the best approach to this task be?

Comment: Look into the `prettytable` package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Scan the keys to produce a list of the distinct column headers and a list of the distinct row headers.
2. Sort each
3. Print out the column headers.
4. For each row header, print out that row looping over the column headers.  For each column/row pair, you can look up the value in the original dictionary

Note that, to get the column header lined up properly, you have to find the longest one.  For the other columns, you would need to scan all of the elements of that column (including the header).

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuples and dictionaries for this task, along with some homespun methods. It'll get grotty fast, though.

It appears that your tuple is a multi-attribute primary key as found in SQL. Consider using `Pandas`--its DataTables have baked-in support for stuff like this.

Comment: Yeah Pandas would be great but this is a part of an assignment to generate a pivot table from scratch (we're not allowed to use Pandas)